# C# Class Property set is not being call nor set

Tags: c#

My class property set is not being call nor is my property being set.
I have a class called StudentDraw  and there is a Property called Student that is that set is not being called. There is my code :

```
 public UserSettings Student
    {
        get => _student;
        set
        {
            if (_student == value) return;
            _student = value;
            UserSettingsChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }
```

Here is how  I  update it :

```
Student.NumberOfPicture ++;
```

here is my UserSettings  class :

```
public class UserSettings
{

    public string CurrentUser;
    public int NumberOfPicture;
   

    public UserSettings()
    {
        CurrentUser = string.Empty;
       NumberOfPicture = 0;
        
    }

}
```

I used breakpoints and it called the Get but it never call the Set with I do :

```
Student.NumberOfPicture ++;
```

Why is this ? and How do I fix it ?

Comment: You never update the `Student` property. You change a property of it only. You're in fact calling its getter, and then the setter of `NumberOfPicture` afterwards.

Comment: @ Alejandro So you are saying I am calling the setting for NumberOfPicture but not for Student? But NumberOfPicture is just a public variable it does not have a setter. Right ?  Should It? Sorry I am not understanding how to fix the problem.

Comment: You haven't explained _what the problem is_. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Your expectation, as @Alejandro has highlighted, is unreasonable since you aren't calling the setter (you are calling the getter).

Comment: @ mjwills, The problems is my set for Student is get being call when I do this: Student.NumberOfPicture ++;  and I do not understand  Alejandro's reply.  Because  I am updating when I am doing this: Student.NumberOfPicture ++. I am adding one to NumberOfPicture and that is inside of Student.

Comment: @ mjwills and  Alejandro, if Student.NumberOfPicture ++ does not call the setter, then how do I call the setter ?

Comment: The setter would be called if you were to call `studentDraw.Student = someNewStudent;`

Where studentDraw is an instance of StudentDraw and someNewStudent is an instance of UserSettings

Comment: @ Chris D it is so weird that you have to do that, but it worked.

Comment: @Bendy - What is so weird? Calling `Student.NumberOfPicture++;` is calling the getter for `Student` and then for `NumberOfPicture`, followed by the setter for `NumberOfPicture`. `Student` is never updated so its setter is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Student.NumberOfPicture++;` is calling the getter for `Student` and then for `NumberOfPicture`, followed by the setter for `NumberOfPicture`. `Student` is never updated so its setter is not called.

Let's look at this simple program:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Student = new Student();
    foo.Student.Counter++;
}

public class Foo
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }= 0;
}
```

That gets compiled to this IL:

```
// (no C# code)
IL_0000: nop
// Foo foo = new Foo();
IL_0001: newobj instance void Foo::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
// foo.Student = new Student();
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_000d: callvirt instance void Foo::set_Student(class Student)
// (no C# code)
IL_0012: nop
// foo.Student.Counter++;
IL_0013: ldloc.0
IL_0014: callvirt instance class Student Foo::get_Student()
IL_0019: dup
IL_001a: callvirt instance int32 Student::get_Counter()
// (no C# code)
IL_001f: stloc.1
IL_0020: ldloc.1
IL_0021: ldc.i4.1
IL_0022: add
IL_0023: callvirt instance void Student::set_Counter(int32)
IL_0028: nop
IL_0029: ret
```

Note that there is a call to `Foo::set_Student` ***before*** `foo.Student.Counter++;`, but after that we see only the following property calls:

```
IL_0014: callvirt instance class Student Foo::get_Student()
IL_001a: callvirt instance int32 Student::get_Counter()
IL_0023: callvirt instance void Student::set_Counter(int32)
```

There is no subsequent call to set the `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix it ?

The reason for the error is that you are changing the field of the UserSettings instance, but expect the setter of the property that uses this instance to be called.
But the instance "does not know" who uses it and how, so it cannot call its not own logic when changing its members.

In the sense of the code you are using, you do not need a class with mutable fields, but an immutable structure.
Also, I do not advise you to use public fields.
In modern C #, this is an anachronism.
Only immutable static fields are used.

An example implementation of the type:

```cs
    public struct UserSettings
    {
        public string CurrentUser { get; }
        public int NumberOfPicture { get; }

        public UserSettings(string currentUser = null, int numberOfPicture = 0)
        {
            CurrentUser = currentUser ?? string.Empty;
            NumberOfPicture = numberOfPicture;
        }

        public UserSettings SetNumber(int numberOfPicture = 0)
            => new UserSettings(this.CurrentUser, numberOfPicture);
        public UserSettings IncrementNumber()
            => new UserSettings(this.CurrentUser, NumberOfPicture + 1);
    }
```

Usage:

```cs
        Student = Student.IncrementNumber();
```

**P.S.**
If, for reasons not specified in the question, you still need a class, not a structure, then change this in the type declaration.
Everything else should remain the same.